# python3 - decorator function: Variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x, methods, grpc, python-decorators, grpc-python

Im working on a [gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python.html) microservice.

Because every method has to load a JSON string from the `request` argument first – and then in the end dump it again, I want to use a decorator on the methods of the class, so that the method itself besides the `return` only contains the `... more stuff to do ...` below:

```
class VPPSetupService(SetupService_pb2_grpc.VPPSetupServiceServicer):
...
   def method(self, request, context):
        request = json.loads(request.context)
        request = request["request"]
        header = request["headers"]
        ... more stuff to do ...
        response = json.dumps(response)
        return SetupService_pb2.JsonContextResponse(context=response)
```

So I wrote a decorator function.
However, I could not find a solution for *this error*:

> request = json.loads(request.context)
>
> > **UnboundLocalError: local variable 'request' referenced before assignment**

The error is produced by this: (Just as an example, the real thing is a bit more complex)

```
from functools import wraps

def json_and_error(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def args_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):           # Problem: This
            request = json.loads(request.context)  <<# variable is referenced
            request = request["request"]             # before assignment
            header = request["headers"]
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return args_wrapper

class VPPSetupService(SetupService_pb2_grpc.VPPSetupServiceServicer):
    ...
       @json_and_error
       def method(self, request, context):
            ... more stuff to do ...
            return SetupService_pb2.JsonContextResponse(context=response)
```

I tried using `request = json.loads(args[1].context)` instead. But then I get this error:

> if request["source_machine"] and request["dest_machine"]: TypeError:
>
> > **'JsonContextRequest' object is not subscriptable**

The input given as `request` argument is an object of type `<class 'SetupService_pb2.JsonContextRequest'>` The JSON String in the request would be accessible through the `request.context` attribute.

*I'm thinking the problem is related to how the decorator function is being called. I suppose if it was called at runtime of the class method the variable request should already have been assigned the request object.*

But maybe I'm **completely** wrong here. So how would you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few errors in your code:

```
def args_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    request = json.loads(request.context)
```

You're using `request.context` while `request` variable is undefined (it will be defined only after `json.loads(request.context)` will be executed). You tried to fix it using `request = json.loads(args[1].context)`, but got `JsonContextRequest object is not subscriptable` in wrapped function. Look at this line closer:

```
return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

You decorator returns wrapped function called with the same params, so this code result isn't used, you don't pass request and header to wrapped function:

```
request = json.loads(request.context)
request = request["request"]
header = request["headers"]
```

Also you shouldn't call wrapped function:

```
func(*args, **kwargs)
```

I guess you want to do something like this:

```
def json_and_error(func):
    def args_wrapper(this, request):
        context = request.context
        request = json.loads(context)
        request = request["request"]

        return func(this, request, context)

    return args_wrapper
```

Comment: Thank you, Ingvar, that kind of makes sense to me. Why should I call the function AND return it. I'll try it out and let you know. 2 questions: Why is it not sufficient to pass *args and **kwargs? I thought this passes all positional and optional parameters? And: I could use self instead of this, and stay with the convention, right?

Comment: 1) passing args and kwargs is more reasonable when you don't know exactly function/methods parameters count, also it makes code less readable (e g `args[1].context)` - what is `args[1]` here?) 2) I used `this` because I wanna mention that `args_wrapper` isn't a method, it's a function. `self` is usually first param in methods. anyway you can use `self` here if you want